# Render child route only after parent route rendered

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have a routing structure

```
  path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'employees', component: EmployeesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
        {path: '', component: EmployeeListComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
        {path: ':id', component: EmployeeMainComponent, pathMatch: 'full',  canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
      ]}
    ]
  }
```

In Main component ngOnInit I get submodules list

```
getSubmodules(id) {
    this.universityAsideService.getSubmodules(id)
      .subscribe((subModules) => {
        this.subModules = subModules;
      this.saveSubModules(subModules).subscribe((data) => this.goToModule(id));
        console.log('submodules in getSubmodules, UniversityAside Co');
        console.log(this.subModules);
      });
  }

  saveSubModules(subModules): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create((obs) => {
      obs.next(localStorage.setItem('subModules', JSON.stringify({
        subModules: subModules
      })));
    });
  }
```

Then Emloyees component get submodules list from localstorage and then renders view. Bu the problem when visiting `localhost:4200/#/employees/` Then employees component tries to get submodules from localstorage before MainComponent save into localstorage. How can I solve this problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the AuthGuard to prevent the rendering of child component before parent component.

Modify the routes like:

```
  path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'employees', component: EmployeesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
        {path: '', component: EmployeeListComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
        {path: ':id', component: EmployeeMainComponent, pathMatch: 'full',  canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
      ]}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.So what can I write in AuthGuard to acheive that? I have no idea. In AuthGuard I check only if user is signed or not.

Comment: check your MainComponent saved into localstorage or not

Comment: you can implement like getModule(id) and use it

Comment: I also found another way . Just render <router-outlet *ngIf="saved"> </router-outlet> with conditon. Thank you!